# jQuery NextUntil like function for phpQuery

Tags: phpquery

Is there any jQuery NextUntil function for phpQuery?
In case I have this HTML structure:

```
<table id="m" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="x" align="center"></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="n"></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="n"></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="x" align="center"></tr>
        <tr class="n"></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="n"></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="n"></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

All I want to do is getting the elements between "tr.x" using phpQuery. In jQuery we can do that with NextUntil() function.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for your purposes:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($children as $child){
    if($i == 2){ break; }
    $i = (pq($child)->attr('class') == 'x') ? ($i + 1) : $i;
    if($i == 0){ continue; }

    echo pq($child)->text();
}
```

**note**: this will also exclude all `tr` elements before the first `tr.x`

for example if the html was..

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="n">h</tr>
    <tr class="x" align="center">a</tr>
    <tr>b</tr>
    <tr class="n">c</tr>
    <tr>d</tr>
    <tr class="n">e</tr>
    <tr>f</tr>
    <tr class="x" align="center">g</tr>
    <tr class="n">h</tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="n"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="n"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

the output would be

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

hope that helps